# Mystery flag of a country

Tags: geography, flags

[image: Image Here]

I have this flag above. The only clue is that this flag belongs to a certain country. If so what country is that? I tried Googling, but it didn't help and I still have no hope.

Clue:

1. 4 syllables
2. Colors: red green white blue and yellow

Comment: Is this a puzzle? Or a question more suited to a different site?

Comment: @titaniummorro it is a puzzle about flags

Comment: Hi Lawrence and welcome to Puzzling! Who set you this challenge, please? Knowing a little about them and where they come from may provide us with more context to help you. Thanks.

Comment: rot13(V'z thrffvat guvf jvyy or rvgure n uvfgbevpny synt, ybat abg va hfr nalzber, be n synt bs n cebivapr/fgngr/pvgl/jungrire, abg n jubyr pbhagel. Gung vf nyfb fhttrfgrq ol gur jbeqvat "vagb n pregnva pbhagel".)

Comment: @Vilx- There's also the matter of rot13(jung lbh qrsvar nf n pbhagel.  Gurer'f pbhagyrff bofpher zvpebangvbaf jubfr syntf zvtug abg fubj hc ba gur hfhny yvfgf.)

Comment: Another thing nobody has yet mooted is that this rot13(pbhyq or n fcbegf-eryngrq onqtr engure guna na npghny angvbany synt). Many people's notion of a 'flag' varies from the dictionary definition...

Comment: You know, the more I look at this, the more it appears to be hand-drawn, like an animation cel from an old cartoon.  rot13(V'z guvaxvat znlor na byq Zrkvpb synt sebz n Fcrrql Tbamnyrm fubeg be fbzrguvat yvxr gung.  Bayl guerr flyynoyrf, ohg vs lbh znxr vg "Ry Zrkvpb", gung'f sbhe...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It looks more like one of those hand stitched felt flags

Comment: @Stiv I have, in fact, investigated this for a few nations.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - You inspired me to post a guess.

Comment: @rtaft Honestly, it looks more like it was part of a screenshot from video game.

Comment: Another possibility is that rot13(gubfr ner abg Yngva punenpgref ng nyy, sbe vafgnapr gur Plevyyvp rdhvinyrag bs FB).

Comment: @IanMacDonald would a video game designer go to so much effort to create uneven stitch lengths in a flag?

Comment: To me the flag looks like it's not rectangular.  I expect it's triangular in shape.  If it were a rectangle you wouldn't be able to see the edge of it in the top right corner of the picture.  The letters also appear to taper to the right.

Comment: @B540Glenn To me it appears that the left side of the flag is closer than the right side, causing the tapering effect. Notice the change of shading between the C and O, indicating that there is some sort of bend or fold there, possibly with the right side of the flag in the image angling away from the camera.

Comment: @rtaft - Sure. Today's games are incredibly well detailed, especially cutscenes. And the tools for making them are highly sophisticated too. I wouldn't be surprised to find a "dashed line with varying dash lengths" tool in Photoshop or whatever.

Comment: Any chance of another hint, @LawrenceAgulto ?

Comment: @Brandon_J it has diamond on its flag

Comment: I think we made a mistake assuming the CO was the country name...for instance, Brazil has "Ordem E Progresso" and not the country name.

Comment: I don't believe I ever assumed so, although I did favor nations with "co" over others.

Comment: Looks like the riddle will not be solved... Care to give at least more hints, if not an outright answer?

Answer (score 8):

A partial answer, which at least rules some things out.

Firstly:

> According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_flag#Current_flags), no current national flag bears what is pictured. I looked through every flag on the list, and I am fairly confident that I did not see the image in the picture. AFAIK, there wasn't even any yellow text on a green background.

For what it's worth,

> I found this to be a most entertaining exercise; I particularly enjoyed the design of the [flag of Kazakhstan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_flag#/media/File:Flag_of_Kazakhstan.svg), one which I don't recall seeing before. The motto on [Malta's flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_flag#/media/File:Flag_of_Malta.svg) was intriguing; I hazard a guess that it is related to the Island's history with the Knights of St. John. Anyways...

It appears that this route is unsuccessful. The next possibility that I examined was

> that a nation had changed its flag recently. According to [this list](https://online.seterra.com/en/p/changed-flags), however, no recently changed flag matches the description. I did check the old South African flag, which was not described in the article. I ought to note that display of this flag in South Africa appears to be considered hate speech, due to its strong ties to the apartheid; this is likely why the old design was not described in the list.

Wikipedia continued to be my friend, as evidenced by

> [this convenient link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flags_by_color_combination#Gold,_white,_red,_blue,_green), which shows more than just national flags. The flag of Rio Grande do Sul appeared promising at first, but had no gold/yellow text on a green background. Pity. For the record, I thought the flag of Tampa, Florida looked pretty sharp.

It is worth listing

> the modern nations that have the mentioned color combination. They are The Comoros (officially The Union of the Comoros), Namibia, and Seychelles. The Virgin Islands, a US "insular area", also has this color combination.

Based on your clues, the two possible nations are

> [The Comoros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoros#/media/File:Flag_of_the_Comoros.svg) and [Namibia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Namibia#/media/File:Flag_of_Namibia.svg)

The flags of these nations does not match the given image, however. Neither does one's seal nor the other's coat of arms.

Something else must be afoot, Watson. I do suspect that the nation is

> The Comoros, since its name includes the C and O from the image.

**Update**

As user [rtaft](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57474/rtaft) pointed out,

> The Comoros did at one point have a shield insignia of some sort that very closely resembles the image; so far, I can only find an image of it [here](https://www.flagline.com/products/comoros-1996-2001-shield-patch). It appears that this patch was manufactured by flagline.com, and I am unsure if this shield was ever official.

**An Updated Update:**

The flagline representative I contacted seemed very interested in this puzzle, haha. They state in an email:

> Fascinating.  I see why it has caused you so much trouble.  It is very unusual for letters to appear on national flags (with the exception of seals on flags but I am not aware of any seals currently that have words on a green background).  In the case of Comoros it actually isn't a C but a crescent for Islam. 
> The clue says it belongs to a country and it seems pretty clear it isn't a national flag and must be a regional or some other sub-national flag.  It is more common to see letters (in a non-seal form) to appear on a flag design for a subnational flag. The colors and style of letters originally made me think of Mexico but nothing else matches.  It isn't clear if the 4 syllables belong to the country or the name of the sub national flag.  Very good puzzle.  Good luck!

So, I'm kind of back at square three.

Comment: Except there appears to be another letter *before* the C, which would rule out that guess.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman that is likely; however, there is also the possibility that it is a border, rather than another letter. Optimism on my part, perhaps?

Comment: The left side could be the edge of a triangle shaped felt flag.  Add in that the old country shield used yellow text and borders on a green background.

Comment: @rtaft ooh, excellent lead! I'll follow it up.

Comment: How can the red in the top right corner be explained?

Comment: It's so almost this image - just need that left edge much closer to the letters...!

Comment: @eyl327 See the 3rd image in the link - it has red edging. (Not an exact match yet but shows it's possible...)

Comment: @eyl327 two ways that I can see: one, there is a similar design that does involve a red stripe or region. Two, the topmost border is in some sort of a shadow, making it appear red. The linked image actually appears to have a red stripe at the top at first glance (IMO). I've contacted the website where I found the image; hopefully they can confirm or deny my theories soon.

Comment: where are the colours as mentioned in the hints? (colors: red green white blue and yellow)

Comment: rot13(V guvax gur yrggref ner gbb fznyy gb gur cbvag bs orvat qvssvphyg gb haqrefgnaq, sbe rknzcyr gur synt bs Irarmhryn, gur fuvryq vafvtavn ba gur synt unf irel fznyy yrggref gung lbh pna bayl ernq ol ybbxvat sbe gur fuvryq vafvtavn vgfrys)

Comment: All of the listed colors are in the current national flag.  I don't think there is red in the shield, it's embroidered so it's likely a single thread color. How do we know that the red in the original picture is part of the flag or the background?

Answer (score 4):

Well, if some strong yellow light was shining on it it would be the flag of

> [New Mexico 1912-1925](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_New_Mexico_(1912-1925).svg)

Answer (score 2):

I think answer is

> South Africa or Namibia

Because

> It has 4 syllables and color which you mention in clues are same .

Comment: South Africa has black in color. Nambia has two syllables if you don't repeat. Prageny Nsevpna Erchoyvp fits good.

Comment: *Namibia, @ManojKumar

Comment: @Brandon_J *Zambia :D

Comment: I am confused...

Answer (score 2):

Several flags fit the clues:

> Costa Rica
>  El Salvador
>  Namibia
>  Nicaragua
>  Venezuela

If there can be more than just the five colors:

> Bolivia
>  South Africa

Although none are inscribed with text containing "CO"

This Wikipedia page did not help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_inscribed_flags

Also, none of these flags have a red area above a large green area.

Comment: Who said there has to be a red area above a green area?  The OP says it contains red and green among other colors, but not necessarily in any particular order.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Look closely at the top right corner, you'll see a red spot there. I think that's what eyl327 is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a wild guess. I cannot find the image you've taken this from, but there's more to sift through and it does seem to fit very well:

> One of the videogames in the "Tropico" series. The word "Tropico" has 3 syllables, plus the number makes 4. For example "Tropico 6".

Comment: You know, I think you're right. The name fits, and the colors of the [flag](https://tropico.fandom.com/wiki/Tropico_(Nation)) as well (spoiler link.) It would make sense that the letters could be stitched on a patch of the flag.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - rot13(Vg pbhyq or sebz fbzr cebzbgvbany ivqrb be znlor rira n snaznqr zbq. Va nqqvgvba, gur pyhr gung "vg pnaabg or sbhaq ba Tbbtyr" vf fhfcvpvbhf.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is :

> Mexico

Comment: I'm not very sure about that, the puzzle implies that image is found within the flag and also 4 syllables

Answer (score 1):

Oooh, DrSheldon *loves* flags.  Obviously, the letters are part of

> SHELDO**N CO**OPER

which is four syllables, and represents the country of

> [apartment 4A](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/The_Official_Apartment_4A_Flag)

Comment: I appreciate the tongue-in-cheek answer, but of course it must be noted that a flag from such a premier scientist would not use such poor kerning.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the answer is

> Seychelles because the flag contains all the colours red, green, white, blue and yellow.
> Couldn't find link with another things.

Comment: Well our user @Brandon_J has already pointed out everything I could think of. He/she definitely deserves a green tick if this is right.